# Automatic identification of Ruby Gems no longer in use within Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Is it possible to automatically identify Ruby gems that are no longer in use within a Rails project?

For example if a fellow developer added gem 'nokogiri' to the Gemfile, for a piece of functionally, but the code that depended on that gem has now been removed. I am looking to port my entire project to jRuby so removing the gems that we no longer seems a very sensible starting point.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually gems are used in a specific way, so for each one you will have to look for patterns manually.

For example, if I had to figure if Nokogiri is being used, I'd use `git grep` to find Nokogiri occurrences (I assume you use git):

```
git grep Nokogiri
```

If nothing is returned, you are probably not using it.

Another way is, if you have a test suite, is just to remove it and see if something breaks. Not foolproof, but if you have good tests it should be a pretty safe path.

Answer (score 0):

On rubyforge there is a gem called [gem_unused](https://rubygems.org/gems/gem_unused).  It adds an 'unused' command to 'gem'.  However, I am not able to test this as it seems to be failing on my system.  (I'm new to the rails world so maybe this is an issue someone else could troubleshoot.  I filed an issue on it on the maintainer's github)

Comment: This looks for gems not used in your Gemset against your project Gemfile.lock. This is not what the author wants.